# What is the best way to recognize document types using artificial intelligence?

Tags: nlp, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, ocr, spacy

guys! I wish you are doing well. What is the best way to recognize document types? The first thing that comes up in my head is to pass the document into a OCR, extract the information of it and then try to find something in that document that does not have on another. For exemple: On a document called R.G, there is an information called "Órgão expedidor" that does not have on another document. In that way I know this is probably an R.G. The problem here is that de OCR process can not recognize the field "Órgão expedidor" on some PDF. Is it the best way to do that task?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Good valid question - not sure why people are downvoting. If you can't rely on OCR to classify, can you use the format of the documents? Do the documents look different visuallly. If they look different, you can convert the page into an image and classify the image using image classification AI. Can you post some sample document pages?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  "What is the best way ... ?" is almost always too broad for this site.

Comment: Thanks, Adnan and Prune for the answer. I will probably not use computer vision to that task. I will probably use OCR and NLP in the end.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create data set, which will cover your domain. Prepare text corpora and assign desired tags to them. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856515/how-to-do-text-classification-using-tensorflow/58875279#58875279) for some tips about corpora embedders.

1. Extract text using some OCR package (i.e. tesseract)
2. Encode text to latent space
3. Train your model

That was the easy way.

It gets harder, when you determine document type based on some visual features. Then you must dive into CNN architectures, as defining those features manually will be mighty hard and error prone.

Comment: Thanks, Piotr! I will probably use OCR and NLP in the end. :)