# How to define a machine learning workflow?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm new into Machine Learning and I would like to have some feedback from you about the workflow that I'm going to follow.

Goal to achieve: Check the accuracy of a text respect to some topic e.g. sport, food, travel etc

Desired output: number between 0 and 1; the closer this value is to 1, the more accurate the text respect to the topic.

Going through tutorials and paper I think should be enough approach my problem by **Text classification**

My workflow:

1. Definition of the dataset. (Already done, circa 10k records)

   - Different records are grouped by category.
2. Creation of the training model
3. Process in Tensorflowjs

About the point nr.1 I made a JSON file and I used the category as label. About the point 2 and 3 I'm looking for some suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856515/how-to-do-text-classification-using-tensorflow/58875279#58875279).

Seems you're quite new to ML, so I'd rather advise against neural nets.
For your needs [xgboost](https://pypi.org/project/xgboost/) will do just fine.
Check out also this [package](https://pypi.org/project/imbalanced-learn/) for resampling data sets. I'd expect more gain from well-balanced data set, than goin straight into deep learning.

`LASER` >> `SVMSMOTE` >> `Tomek-Links` >> `XGBClassier` would be good starting pipeline.